# Is it possible to check a GMail account for unread email with a certain Label attached to it?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to build an electronic device using a Micro-Controller that will do something such as light up an LED light or display information on an LED screen when I have new un-read emails from a user that is in my short-list or VIP list of user mails.  These are clients that I need to be able to respond to their emails ASAP and I would like to build a device to alert me when an email from them exist without having to constantly check my email in a browser or application on the computer.

So I know this is sounding like a hardware question but for the time being I am asking for help or direction on how to do the software side of it only.

My electronic device will likely be able to connect to the internet so I am thinking I should be able to build a simple application in PHP or JavaScript, the main languages I use daily for work.

So I am asking if it's even possible right now to for example...

1. Connect and check my Gmail account
2. Then check to see if there is NEW UN-READ email that is from a list of "VIP/Client" emails or even better if it's possible to check if the un-read email has a certain "Label" applied to it?

If I can get the PHP script to do this then I can build a simple device with one of these which can then call the script...

- Raspberry Pi - http://www.raspberrypi.org/ (computer running Linux)
- Arduino - http://www.arduino.cc/ (8bit micro controller)
- Tessel.io - https://tessel.io/ (Runs JavaScript + NodeJS + WiFi built-in)

Also I am open to any other ideas to accomplish my end goal of creating some sort of Alert System for new emails from important clients...solutions that do not use a Smart Phone?

Comment: Yes; you can connect via IMAP and use the SEARCH command.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/it/function.imap-search.php

Comment: @SLaks Yup, absolutely possible. Consider using PHP IMAP : https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap

Comment: You will also need to use Gmail's IMAP extensions to search or fetch labels.  https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions

Comment: Great comments it sounds like you all are pointing me in a good direction for something I have wanted to do for a long time

Comment: Another completely different alternative is to have a look at [If This Than That (IFTT)](http://www.ifttt.com) - more specifically, something like [`this`](https://ifttt.com/recipes/93263-if-i-receive-an-email-from-a-specific-address-then-blink-lights-to-notify-me) using phillips Hue light bulbs :)